# Who controls the Payment Hub in tumblebit?

Tags: governance, tumblebit

Who controls the "Payment Hub" in tumblebit?

Is it another protocol or company or is there something else / someone else involved?

Comment: I believe you're misunderstanding something. The payment hub is just part of the TumbleBit scheme. Its operator controls it.

Comment: I've retagged this, as it doesn't relate to sidechains or blockchain.

Answer (score 1):

The notion is that anyone with sufficient Bitcoins to act as collateral for the payment channels could setup a TumbleBit payment hub. This would likely be a company.

The more users a TumbleBit payment hub has the greater the privacy and utility offered so one would expect a small number of payment hubs with many users.